# MySQL find closest integer between two columns

Tags: mysql

Right now, I have an IP which I am converting to an integer and then trying to find the closest match to a location from a table.

[image]

I'm doing this right now:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE IP_FROM >= $x AND IP_TO <= $x LIMIT 1;";
```

and sometimes I get no result as $x falls through the cracks.

I'd like to know of a way where I can get the closest row.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with LEAST, e.g.:

```
select * 
from Table1 t 
order by LEAST(abs(t.IP_FROM - 123), abs(t.IP_TO - 123)) 
LIMIT 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c7a/17/0)

Comment: This query will always do a full table scan. The geoip database has over 100,000 records, and the geoip_city database has over 3 million records. Not the kind of tables you want to do table scans on. This answer will not do a table scan: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12114949/1432614

Answer (score 1):

This should work in all cases:

```
(SELECT * FROM geoip FORCE INDEX (IP_FROM) WHERE IP_FROM <= $x ORDER BY IP_FROM DESC LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM geoip FORCE INDEX (IP_TO) WHERE IP_TO >= $x ORDER BY IP_TO LIMIT 1)
```

This will give you two rows, if the first row is not the row you want, the second row will be.

[SqlFiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d35be/14)

Comment: this doesn't give accurate results.  In one example the first row would be London and the second row would be Southampton.

Comment: I modified the query, please try it again.